# 2.91, using the apply as rest pose function in the Cats blender plugin, the keyword "apply_as" unrecognized appears

Tags: modeling, python

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\cats-blender-plugin-master\tools\armature_manual.py", line 285, in execute
pose_to_shapekey('PoseToRest')
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\cats-blender-plugin-master\tools\armature_manual.py", line 193, in pose_to_shapekey
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='SHAPE', modifier=mod.name)
File "I:\blender\2.91\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in **call**
ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "apply_as" unrecognized

location: :-1

Comment: Please add more of a description to your problem in your question. Simply putting the code makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: This is an error raised by an outdated add-on. The modifier_apply method no longer has an apply_as keyword parameter. If you’ve redownloaded the addon and it has not had a new release (i.e. the problem persists), raise an issue on GitHub or edit the code yourself locally.